# How to display the picker when touch down the text field in static table view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In TableViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)genderSelection:(id)sender;
```

In TableViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)genderSelection:(UIControl *)sender {
    
    
    ActionStringDoneBlock done = ^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker, NSInteger selectedIndex, id selectedValue) {
        if ([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(setText:)]) {
            [sender performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:selectedValue];
        }
    };
    ActionStringCancelBlock cancel = ^(ActionSheetStringPicker *picker) {
        NSLog(@"Block Picker Canceled");
    };
    NSArray *gender= @[@"Male", @"Female"];
    [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select a Block" rows:gender initialSelection:0 doneBlock:done cancelBlock:cancel origin:sender];
  
}
```

I'm using the [ActionSheetPicker-3.0]. I wish to display the picker ( the gender male or female). When the user touch down the text field , it's display the male or female picker . I try the code for normal view controller its work but not in the static tabletableviewController. Anyone know how to display the picker ?

The image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0edkr.png

The picker is able to display in ViewController but not the static TableViewController.

The picker image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DJ7c.png